# At large times, $\sin(\omega t)$ tends to zero?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, asymptotics, quantum-mechanics

While doing a calculation in quantum mechanics, I got a expression $\sin(\omega t)$, and my prof said if I consider the consider at large times, then i can assume that this goes to zero because at large times, the graph of $\sin$ oscillates very rapidly and so you can take it to be zero. When i asked about this he said we want to check for $\frac{\Delta t}{t}$(no units) which should be invariant, and so at large times, we need to take long time(means many cycles) for same ration of $\frac{\Delta t}{t}$.

But I wasn't convinced by this explanation. I want to know is this mathematically consistent.

Comment: Well the explanation that sin oscillates very rapidly at large $t$ is vague. It's just like $sin(2x)$ ,which have same time period.this should be askeed like a limit question as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}sinx$$ , ie. indeterminate.But ofcoure it's bound in $[-1,1]$ `;p`

Comment: so how do we find the limit?

Comment: It's indeterminate and can't be found.We can't define infinity as $2n\pi+\theta$ and find $\lim{x\to\theta}sinx$ because \infinity is not defined. If you say $infinity = 2n\pi+\pi/3$ . I'll say what about $infinity = 2n\pi+\pi/6$? .So, it's indeterminate.Just post the physics question on Physics.SE maybe I can help you with the question itself there.